# How do I locate Service Address (URL) and/or troubleshoot Mailtrain instance on Amazon ECS?

Tags: docker, redis, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Apologies for any newbie questions as I am new to both Docker and AWS. I'm trying to deploy a [Mailtrain](https://github.com/Mailtrain-org/mailtrain) instance with Amazon Fargate.

I've created a Docker image per Mailtrain's docs and uploaded it to Amazon ECR. I then created a new task using Fargate, linked to the Docker image I'd uploaded. Part of Mailtrain's config docs say to specify a Service Address (URL) where the Mailtrain can be reached. I entered the load balancer address here but get nothing when I try to navigate to that address in my browser.

Looking at my AWS dashboard, the task seems to stop as soon as it starts. The only hint I'm seeing is in this error: `Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis redis:6379`.

I have successfully configured Mailtrain on my local machine and can access it via `localhost:3000`. I can create the Docker image and upload to ECR with no problem. I specified the image address when creating my ECS task. But I'm a little lost on how to troubleshoot from here.

How can I:

- Verify I'm using the correct URL to try to access my Mailtrain login page?
- Begin to troubleshoot why my task keeps failing?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, seeing a getaddrinfo on redis:6379 probably means, you use docker-compose on local environment with link to a docker named redis, right? 
You did not specify how do you connect it in production? did you configure a side-car container named redis with a link to your container as well? If not, start there, if you did add it, check that you did not change default docker name server in task config.

Regarding reaching the server, your server must be configured in a public subnet to be able to pull the docker image from ecr + reach it outside of your VPC, later, if you added a load balancer, make sure its security group is allowed to access the target group of where your instances run.

Third, check that all your instance/target group/lb healthchecks pass, if not, it means they cant reach each other due to security group access.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never used a container called redis, I'm assuming this is something running on ECS. As for connecting in production, I linked my Docker image to the task I created using Fargate on Amazon ECS. I suppose I'm not seeing how redis fits into this whole picture as it's not included in either Amazon's or Mailtrain's documentation.

Comment: @jaclyn you said there is a redis ENOTFOUND, it must come from somewhere. Can you show me your docker-compose/docker.yml?

Comment: Ah yes, in that file there is a reference to redis:

```redis:
    image: redis:3.0
    volumes:
      - mailtrain-redis-data:/data```

Comment: The mailtrain image name is also listed in `docker-compose.yml` as `image: mailtrain:latest`, which isn't the same name I use on my remote server. Wondering if I need to change it to `[remote-image-name]:latest`.